# hierarchical query without side rows

Tags: sql, oracle, connect-by, hierarchical-query

I have "id-parent_id related" data, like this:

```
      1
     / \
    /   \
   2     4
  /
 /
3
```

I have the code, that returns data for all rows related to particular (related to condition in the `start with` clause) tree - in both sides ("up" and "down"), for example:

```
with
  temp_cte(id, parent_id) as
    (select 1, null from dual
     union all
     select 2, 1 from dual
     union all
     select 3, 2 from dual
     union all
     select 4, 1 from dual
     union all
     select 5, null from dual)
select *
from temp_cte t
connect by nocycle (prior id = parent_id) or (prior parent_id = id)
start with t.id = 2
order by id
```

**How do i get data without "side" ("right"/"left") rows?**
e.g. for the drawn above -

I need data without `4` when I start with `2 or 3`,

and I need data without `2 and 3` when I start with `4`

(if `start with 1`, I still want the full tree)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because of `OR` predicate in `CONNECT BY`: your query traverses in both directions, so on the second step of `CONNECT BY` you'll have all the childs of the parent and finally all the tree.

You need to split the query into union of two directions.

> ```
> with
>   temp_cte(id, parent_id) as
>     (select 1, null from dual
>      union all
>      select 2, 1 from dual
>      union all
>      select 3, 2 from dual
>      union all
>      select 4, 1 from dual
>      union all
>      select 5, null from dual
> )
>
> select id, parent_id
> from temp_cte t
> where level > 1
> connect by nocycle (prior id = parent_id)
> start with t.id = 2
>
> union all
>
> select id, parent_id
> from temp_cte t
> connect by (prior parent_id = id)
> start with t.id = 2
> order by id
> ```
>
> ```
> ID | PARENT_ID
> -: | --------:
>  1 |      null
>  2 |         1
>  3 |         2
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=ce3cee4132b0935d55d69b4886f786ac)*

Comment: It would be simpler to stick the condition `where level > 1` in one of the branches of `union all` - then you wouldn't need the over-query. Since you order by `id` anyway (ignoring hierarchical order), you can stick the `order by` clause at the end; it always applies to the result of `union all` (or any other set-theoretical operation), not just to the last branch.

Comment: @mathguy Thank you, you are right. I've missed something at query design time which gave me some problem I didn't remember. Edited my answer with more clear and straightforward code